# SSH Unable to resolve Hostname when using alias

Tags: ssh

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on an *RPi 3 model B* which I want to access using SSH

Using the long command:

```
$ ssh username@hostname
```

OR

```
$ ssh username@pi.ip.add.ress
```

I am able to successfully ssh into my RPi. But after creating the alias in `~/.ssh/config` like:

```
Host myshortuser
    User username
    Hostname pi.ip.add.ress
```

and then try the command:

```
$ ssh myshortuser
```

I get the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myshortuser: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: There is no alias in your example.

Comment: It's not the case sensitivity of the `HostName` stanza either. I just tested it. I'm afraid you have to provide more details, @Hassaan. For example we have no clue what's in your `/etc/ssh_config` or what global options you may have set in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77986/discussion-between-0xc0000022l-and-christopher).

Comment: Run `ssh -vv myshortuser id 2>&1 > sshoutput.log`.  Then look in `sshoutput.log` for any errors.  Your system doesn't seem to be reading the `~/.ssh/config` file.  That may be due to permissions, or due to a system wide restriction on reading user files.

Comment: Just for clarification, my setup only has **1 PC and 2 RPis** connected to the **same network**, with nothing else connected, so it is much more simple than servers on different networks. 
In the **Pi**, all users are in `sudo` group, so there is no issue of permission to edit any files either. 
I will have access to the Pi tomorrow, so I will post further comments again after running the commands shared here. 
Just to be sure, the **permission** of `~/..ssh` and its contents should be `0700`, right?

Comment: In case this question is still alive, the configuration file belongs on your (unspecified) client, and not on the destination system (the Pi)

Comment: Please clarify in the question what system the `~/.ssh/config` file resides on (it should be the system you are connecting _from_).  Also ensure that the permissions and ownerships of the `~/.ssh` and its contents are correct. Can we assume that you are not using `sudo` to run `ssh`, for example?

Answer (score -1):

please make sure the hostname is unique in your network.

sudo nano /etc/hosts --> will show the list of the hostnames. 
Please change the hostname at 127.0.1.1

to make the changes effected, please run

sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh

sudo reboot

Comment: The hostname created is unique; there is no other system in my network with the same hostname.